# Working on spin and promela

Tags: model-checking, spin, promela

Firstly, I always get this problem of depth reached:0. I tried every possibility. Secondly, i want to reach those states mentioned in ltl formula. So is this syntax correct or not?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: made out of the link a inline image

Comment: Also, the error message you obtain clearly suggests a possible solution.. It's unclear whether you tried following it, which values you tried and what was the outcome.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin sir, I don't know what to do with this. Please give me your email id. I want to discuss it with you. Why this problem of depth reached 0 is occurring again and again.

Comment: Sir, actually i don't write this code. This is generated from a tool. I insert only ltl formula and check it on spin. My work is based on this link [http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7800314] . Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About the error**

Spin clearly explains what is happening:

> VECTORSZ too small, recompile pan.c with -DVECTORSZ=N with N>1024;
>
> aborting (at depth 0)

that is why you get

> State-vector 1024 byte, depth reached 0, errors: 1

So I would try with

> gcc -DVECTORSZ=2048 -o pan pan.c

**About the LTL formula**

You have a lot of unnecessary brackets; you can write simpler:

```
<>( (m[7]==2) && (m[11]==1) && (m[20]==1) && (m[54]==1) & (m[57]==1) && (m[81]==1) )
```

So you have a pretty large array `m`, which explains why your state vector of 1024 bytes is not sufficient. A better solution than increasing the state vector would be decreasing the size of `m` if you can still check the property you are interested in with `m`abstracted in some way.

You write you "want to reach those states mentioned in your ltl formula". The ltl formula is checked for each path, so on each path a state must eventually be reached in which all clauses of your logical conjunction must hold. If you want to find a path that reaches a state in which all clauses of your logical conjunction hold, negate your ltl formula, i.e. []( disjunction of your negated clauses ), and look at the (end of your) counterexample path in case such a state is reachable.

Comment: Thanku so much sir @DaveFar..this has been so helpful.

Comment: @Amrita Dahiya: Happy I could help. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.